# Angular2 cant acces variable anywhere but in template

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have problem with accesing array inside component in place other than template.
I have  `students: Student[];` which is then filled by data from json in

```
getStudents() {
    this.studentService.getStudents()
        .subscribe(
        students => this.students = students,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error );
}
```

I can display this data in template via

```
<tr *ngFor="let student of students">
    <td>{{ student.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.firstName }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.lastName }}</td>
</tr>
```

but, if I try to do something like

```
this.students.forEach(
            s => {
                console.log(s.getFirstName());
            });
```

i get `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

If I however initialize array as `students: Student[] = new Array;` i dont get error, but array stays empty. Method getStudents() is called from ngOnInit().
What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Thanks everyone who tried to help. However none of the solutions worked for me. getStudents() is first method I call in ngOnInit. I just dont understand, why does listing it in template work, but for rest of component array appears to be empty. If I add values to array later, via students.push, they are only values I can access.

Comment: where are you using this.students.forEach ?

Comment: Is data being returned from the `studentService` as an array?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `elvis operator` white fetching data from service like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let student of students">
    <td>{{ student?.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ student?.firstName }}</td>
    <td>{{ student?.lastName }}</td>
</tr>
```

No need to use `forEach`

> sometimes `template` loads before getting data from the service so in this case elvis operator will prevent from throwing error

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

When you declared students objects like

```
students: Student[]
```

please take a deep look into it. you are declaring variable[students] of array of student not initialize it. that means your students is null. So when you are using forEach  method on null you you are getting error like  'Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined'

you can do like

```
students: Student[] = [];
```

then use 'forEach' hope. you will not get any error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have mentioned in post that if I initialize array, it doesnt give error but array stays empty.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is combination of the the `students` array not being initialized when the `forEach` is run and with how Angular2's life-cycle hooks work.

`ngOnInit` is the second method that is called when a component is created, after an initial call to `ngOnChanges`. If the call to `this.studentService.getStudents()` hasn't returned by the time the the `forEach` is called then the error will occur because the `students` array has not been initialized yet.

The `ngOnInit` method only gets called once for each component so the reason you aren't seeing any data printed to the console is that when the loop is called it has not received data from the service yet.

I am not sure what your use case is but what I like to do when I need to perform actions on data returned from a service is to create a function that I call from the service callback:

```
getStudents() {
    this.studentService.getStudents()
        .subscribe(
            students => {
                this.students = students;
                this.printStudents();
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error );
}

printStudents() {
    this.students.forEach(
        s => {
            console.log(s.getFirstName());
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didnt help.